# Autoloading both Classes & Models

Tags: php, autoloader

I know it's common practice to autoload your controllers when using an MVC framework. I have made my own mini-framework where controllers are autoloaded fine.

Are there any security/bad issues with having the same autoload function load the models too?

I.e.

```
function __autoload($className) { // Autoload both controllers and models.
if(stristr($className, 'Model'))
{
    if (is_readable(Ms . $className . '.php')) {
        include Ms . $className . '.php';
    }
} else {
    if (is_readable(Cs . $className . '.php')) {
        include Cs . $className . '.php';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you should be using `spl_autoload_register()`, and your magical autoloader does not support namespaces.

Comment: @tereško do you mean if he should use `spl_autoload_register()` "directly" without encapsulating it into some class like `Autoloader` or `Import`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use namespaces and `spl_autoload_register()` in order to get such an autoloader. There's no specific security issues regarding a multi autoloader (an autoloader for multi classes of classes) rather than a controller-only autoloader.

I usually works with namespaces like:

```
$home = new controller\home;
$home->actionIndex();

$users = new model\users;

$post = new view\post;
```

from there it's easy to replace a `\` in the class name with a `/` to get the specific paths for the file (obviously doing the needed security checking as always).